# Array issues in search with Web Api

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire

I've written a view that search elements with a specified parameter (username or role).
The requests are sent to a web api, which returns JSON data with the result users.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire


class searchViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


let headers = ["tb-token" : userToken!]

var loadedMode:Bool = false
var resultsN = 0
var resultsDict = NSArray()

//Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var wallpaper: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var searchButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfResults: UILabel!


//Search action
@IBAction func search(sender: AnyObject) {

    let searchString = searchField.text//.lowercaseString
    let trimmedString = searchString!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())


    if trimmedString.hasPrefix("@"){


        let usernameString = trimmedString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("@", withString: "")


        Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.Path.rootUrl + "/api/users", parameters: ["username" : usernameString, "limit":3] , headers: ["tb-token" : userToken!])
            .responseJSON { _, _, JSON in


                print(JSON.value)


                self.tableView.hidden = false

                if JSON.isSuccess == true {

                    self.resultsDict = JSON.value as! NSArray

                    let results = JSON.value
                    let resultsNumber = results!.count

                    self.numberOfResults.text = "Results(\(resultsNumber))"
                    self.numberOfResults.hidden = false

                    self.resultsN = resultsNumber
                    self.loadedMode = true
                    self.tableView.reloadData()


                } else { print("false") }

        }




    } else {

        Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.Path.rootUrl + "/api/users",parameters: ["role" : trimmedString, "limit" : 20], headers: ["tb-token" : userToken!])
            .responseJSON { _, _, JSON in


                print(JSON.value)


                self.resultsDict = JSON.value as! NSArray

                let results = JSON.value
                let resultsNumber = results!.count

                self.numberOfResults.text = "Results(\(resultsNumber))"
                self.numberOfResults.hidden = false

                self.resultsN = resultsNumber
                self.loadedMode = true
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.tableView.hidden = false



        }
    }

}





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //Setting the delegate for the results table
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    //Setting the delegate for the search text field
    searchField.delegate = self


    //Adding the gesture recogniser to hide keyboard on tap
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


    let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let theHeight = view.frame.size.height


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        self.wallpaper.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theWidth, theHeight)
        self.wallpaper.alpha = 0.85


        self.searchField.frame = CGRectMake(60, 70, theWidth-90, self.searchField.frame.height+7)
        self.searchField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.view.addSubview(self.searchField)


        self.searchButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchField.frame.minX+5 - self.searchField.frame.height, self.searchField.frame.minY-0.5, self.searchField.frame.height, self.searchField.frame.height+0.8)
        self.view.addSubview(self.searchButton)

        self.numberOfResults.frame = CGRectMake(25, self.searchField.frame.maxY + 20, 150, 30)
        self.numberOfResults.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        self.numberOfResults.hidden = true

        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.searchField.frame.maxY + 50, theWidth, theHeight - self.searchField.frame.maxY - 40)
        self.tableView.hidden = true
    }


    searchField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    searchField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChangeNow:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

}



func textFieldDidChangeNow(textField: UITextField) {

    search(self)

}



//Tet changes color when searching for username
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {


    if textField.text!.hasPrefix("@") == true {

        textField.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    } else {

        textField.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    }


}



//Hide keyboard on screen tap
func DismissKeyboard(){

    view.endEditing(true)

}


//Hide keyboard when "Return" is pressed
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    view.endEditing(true)

    return false

}



//UITableView defaul functions
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if loadedMode == true {

        return resultsN

    } else {

        return 1
    }


}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchResult") as! SearchResultTableViewCell


    if loadedMode == false {

        return cell
    } else {



        let username = resultsDict[indexPath.row].objectForKey("username") as! String

        Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.Path.rootUrl + "/api/users/?username=" + username +  "&fields=image", headers: self.headers)
            .responseJSON { _,_, JSON in


                let array = JSON.value?.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
                let imageString = array.objectForKey("image") as! String
                let imageUrl = NSURL(string: imageString)
                //cell.profilePic.sd_setImageWithURL(imageUrl)


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    let imageData = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl!)!)
                    cell.profilePic.image = imageData?.circleMask
                    cell.profilePic.frame.size.width = 70
                    cell.profilePic.frame.size.height = 70
                    cell.profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePic.frame.width/2
                    cell.profilePic.layer.masksToBounds = true
                    cell.profilePic.clipsToBounds = true

                    cell.username.frame =  CGRectMake(cell.profilePic.frame.maxX+5, cell.profilePic.frame.minY, 120, 20)
                    cell.role.frame = CGRectMake(cell.profilePic.frame.maxX+5, cell.username.frame.maxY+7, 180, 20)
                    cell.username.text = self.resultsDict[indexPath.row].objectForKey("name") as? String
                    cell.role.text = self.resultsDict[indexPath.row].objectForKey("role") as? String

                }


        }




        return cell


    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
}
```

However, I think I messed up with background tasks, so I get this kind of error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (3) beyond bounds (3)

*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111aebf65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111565deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111aebe9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111a0cb63 -[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:] + 163
4   TeamBuilding No Parse               0x000000010fd0471d _TFFFC21TeamBuilding_No_Parse20searchViewController9tableViewFS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCellU_FTGSqCSo12NSURLRequest_GSqCSo17NSHTTPURLResponse_GO9Alamofire6ResultPSs9AnyObject___T_U_FT_T_ + 4349
5   TeamBuilding No Parse               0x000000010fccc9e7 _TTRXFo__dT__XFdCb__dT__ + 39
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001148f7ef9 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011491849b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011490034b _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111a4c3e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111a0d939 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111a0ce98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
12  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000117acaad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
13  UIKit                               0x0000000112797676 UIApplicationMain + 171
14  TeamBuilding No Parse               0x000000010fd2b91d main + 109
15  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011494c92d start + 1
16  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Can someone identifies the problems in my code? Thank you!

Comment: Please post the stack trace. And why `return 1` instead of `return 0`?

Comment: Added @Droppy.

Probably that's an issue, but the function requires to return a non-zero value.

Comment: That stack trace doesn't appear to help at all; I've never seen symbols like that.